# Create dict by successive updates in a comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a function that outputs a dictionary:

```
def mkdict(i):
    # Simplified example
    return {i: i, 2*i: 2*i}
```

I'm building a `dict` using this function.

```
result = {}
for i in range(5):
    result.update(mkdict(i))
print(result)
# result = {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 6: 6, 8: 8}
```

Is there a way I could make `result` in a single line using a comprehension?

Something like

```
result = {mkdict(i) for i in range(5)}
result = {**mkdict(i) for i in range(5)}
```

Comment: that would be a nice syntax addition, same for creating a flat list with few elements each time using `*`, let's make it happen in Python 3.9 :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comprehensions (list, set, dict, and generator expressions) all work on the principle of handling *single items*. A function that produces two key-value pairs is not a single item, so you need to split the result into single items. Comprehensions do not support [PEP 448 unpacking syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/), those only apply to the non-comprehension forms.

You'd have to add an extra loop over the `dict.items()` of the returned dictionary:

```
{k: v for i in range(5) for k, v in mkdict(i).items()}
```

You can also use the `dict()` type, as it accepts an iterable of key-value pairs:

```
dict(item for i in range(5) for item in mkdict(i).items())
```

You can also use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

dict(chain.from_iterable(mkdict(i).items() for i in range(5)))
```

If `mkdict()` was implemented in a compiled language (from a library or implemented with Cython, etc.) and the number of iterations is large enough, it may be worth the drop in readability and use the [`map()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to apply the `mkdict()` function to the range values and the unbound `dict.items` method to each dictionary produced:

```
dict(chain.from_iterable(map(dict.items, map(mkdict, range(5)))))
```

Here, this doesn't make much odds as `mkdict()` is implemented in Python and so `map()` has to call back into the Python interpreter to get the dictionary. But for functions that don't do this, the above expression executes iteration and dictionary handling entirely in native machine code, avoiding the Python interpreter loop altogether.

Demo of each of these options:

```
>>> def mkdict(i):
...     # Simplified example
...     return {i: i, 2*i: 2*i}
...
>>> {k: v for i in range(5) for k, v in mkdict(i).items()}
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 4: 4, 3: 3, 6: 6, 8: 8}
>>> dict(item for i in range(5) for item in mkdict(i).items())
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 4: 4, 3: 3, 6: 6, 8: 8}
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> dict(chain.from_iterable(mkdict(i).items() for i in range(5)))
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 4: 4, 3: 3, 6: 6, 8: 8}
>>> dict(chain.from_iterable(map(dict.items, map(mkdict, range(5)))))
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 4: 4, 3: 3, 6: 6, 8: 8}
```

Note that PEP 448 explicitly excluded comprehensions, but the path is open for future Python releases adding something like that to the language. Quoting from the [PEP abstract section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/#abstract):

> This PEP does not include unpacking operators inside list, set and dictionary comprehensions although this has not been ruled out for future proposals.

Comment: Thanks. Overall, I'm leaning towards keeping the initial 3 lines form for readability, but thanks for the detailed explanation. I was looking for some sort of generalization of the `{**a, **b, **c,...}` form.

Comment: @Jérôme: that form only applies to *key-datum lists*, one of two ways you can produce a dictionary (the other being a dict comprehension). See the [reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays).

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) to repeatedly reduce the input dictionaries into one.

Given your example:

```
def mkdict(i):
    return {i: i, 2*i: 2*i}

dicts = [mkdict(i) for i in range(5)]
```

The following code (a somewhat elegant one-liner):

```
from functools import reduce

result = reduce(lambda a, b: {**a, **b}, dicts)
```

Produces `{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 4: 4, 3: 3, 6: 6, 8: 8}` - note that dictionaries later in the sequence would overwrite previous keys.